# Cast error when using populate, works on localhost but error on heroku mongolab

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

errCastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5874b2ee859d3000127b95f1" at path "_id" for model "Item"

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  uid: String,
  email: String,
  name: String,
  lastname: String,
  reset: Boolean,
  cap: Number,
  verified: Boolean,
  inventory: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'
  }]
});
var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  description: String,
  youtube: String,
  sent: Boolean,
  date: Date
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

I use firebase to manage the users so I need firebase uid.

```
router.get('/my', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({uid: req.user.uid}).populate('inventory').exec(function(err, user){
    if(err) console.log('asda',err);
    console.log('user is',user);
    res.send(user.inventory);
  });
});
```

Here's a user and an item in that order from mongolab.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5874a9fb53377a0012fe83db"
    },
    "uid": "89ed4720-cea6-4f0d-bcd0-4fc1f4a0bf2b",
    "email": "hey@heyhey.edu",
    "name": "Kaan",
    "lastname": "Kocturk",
    "reset": false,
    "verified": true,
    "cap": 2,
    "inventory": [
        {
            "$oid": "5874b2ee859d3000127b95f1"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 1
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5874b2ee859d3000127b95f1"
    },
    "name": "kaan",
    "email": "kkocturk1@bbb.edu",
    "description": "HAAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAH",
    "youtube": "",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2017-01-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "sent": false,
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is my first ever production website and I just am not good enough to solve this on my own. I looked at other solutions but couldn't figure it out... Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of your data? A user and an item please?

Comment: I added those, thanks already @ThomasBormans

Comment: Have you tried adding the ObjectId as string? Like this: "inventory": ["5874b2ee859d3000127b95f1"]

Comment: If you mean changing "inventory: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'
  }]" to type: String I just tried it, didn't work. But I don't think I understand what you mean. @ThomasBormans

Comment: I mean the user data in your database. Not the model.

Comment: So this is how I do that process: 
item.save(function(err, saveditem) {
        user.inventory.push(saveditem._id);
what should I change I don't understand sorry @ThomasBormans

Comment: Wait. How did you get the document from the user collection? Did you use `mongoexport` or just navigated in the db?

Comment: I have mongolabs as an add-on on heroku. I just accessed the documents from the dashboard and copy pasted them here. I basically used nothing but the mouse. @ThomasBormans

Comment: Hmmm. Can you maybe make a little example that I can test locally?

Comment: The weird thing is, it works on localhost but not on heroku. so it wouldnt do any good im afraid @ThomasBormans

Comment: Have you checked your MongoDB version on Heroku and on your local machine?